# Search using username or email using like function in two table in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
user        user_details

id          id
username    username
email       email
password    firstname
balance     lastname
etc         address
....        etc...
```

What will be my sql command in Codeigniter if I search all `username` start with A in both table. I want also all the values from two tables.

Comment: What is the relation between user and user_details table?

Answer (score 0):

In mysql:

```
select u.*, ud.* from users u, user_details ud where u.username like "%A%" and ud.username like "%A%"
```

Something like this in Codeigniter:

```
$sql = "select u.*, ud.* from users u, user_details ud where u.username like '%A%' and ud.username like '%A%'"
$this->db->query($sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->from('userdetail');
$this->db->like('username','A','after');
$this->db->get();
```

try this may be help u